# React Tanstack Tables How to insert dynamically changing columns?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-table, tanstack

I have not been able to find an example which is not using hardcoded values for columns.

I want to make a table that has One guaranteed column which will have a description/label etc and then n columns that contain dates.

I have the following code which renders perfectly fine.

```
const newColumns = [
        {
            id: 'rowName',
            accessor: 'rowName',
            header: 'rowName',
            enableSorting: true,
        },
            ...datesFiltered.map(timestamp => ({
                id: timestamp.toString(),
                accessor: timestamp.toString(),
                header: monthNames[new Date(timestamp).getMonth()] + ' ' + new Date(timestamp).getFullYear(),
                enableSorting: true,
        })),
      ];
```

However, I can not for the life of me get the rows to render at all.

This is the original data structure i have which i get from an api I made.

```
type NestedDictionary = {
  [key: number]: {
    [key: string]: number;
  };
};
```

It is literally a dict with a key of timestamp and a value variable and value embedded dict. Where the variable is what i want in the first column of my table.

I have tried a few different ways of formatting the data but i havent had any luck so far.

Currently I am trying to do it like this

```
let arr:any = []
if (data !== null) {
            const allKeys = Array.from(new Set(Object.values(data).flatMap(Object.keys)));
            allKeys.forEach((key) => {
                const tableData: { [key: string]: string | number }[] = [];
                const row: { [key: string]: string | number } = {metric: key, id: "rowName",cell:key};
                row[key] = key || '-';
                tableData.push(row);
                
              Object.entries(data).forEach(([year, values]) => {
                if(datesFiltered.includes(Number(year))){
                  
                  const row: { [key: string]: string | number } = {metric: key, id: year.toString(),cell:values[key]||"-"};
                  tableData.push(row);
                } 
              });arr.push(tableData);
            });
        }
```

This is the table code:

```
import React from 'react'
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom/client'



import {
  flexRender,
  getCoreRowModel,
  getSortedRowModel,
  SortingState,
  useReactTable,
} from '@tanstack/react-table'

interface InteractiveTableProps {
  data:any[][];
  columns:any;
}
export const InteractiveTable: React.FC<InteractiveTableProps> = ({data, columns}) => {

  const [sorting, setSorting] = React.useState<SortingState>([])

  const table = useReactTable({
    data,
    columns,
    state: {
      sorting,
    },
    onSortingChange: setSorting,
    getCoreRowModel: getCoreRowModel(),
    getSortedRowModel: getSortedRowModel(),
    debugTable: true,
  })
  if(table){
    console.log(table)
    return (
      <div className="p-2 text-primary">
        <div className="h-2" />
        <table>
          <thead>
            {table.getHeaderGroups().map(headerGroup => (
              <tr key={headerGroup.id}>
                {headerGroup.headers.map(header => {
                  return (
                    <th key={header.id} colSpan={header.colSpan}>
                      {header.isPlaceholder ? null : (
                        <div
                          {...{
                            className: header.column.getCanSort()
                              ? 'cursor-pointer select-none'
                              : '',
                            onClick: header.column.getToggleSortingHandler(),
                          }}
                        >
                          {flexRender(
                            header.column.columnDef.header,
                            header.getContext()
                          )}
                          {{
                            asc: ' ',
                            desc: ' ',
                          }[header.column.getIsSorted() as string] ?? null}
                        </div>
                      )}
                    </th>
                  )
                })}
              </tr>
            ))}
          </thead>
          <tbody>
            {table
              .getRowModel()
              .rows
              .map(row => {
                return (
                  <tr key={row.id}>
                    {row.getVisibleCells().map(cell => {
                      return (
                        <td key={cell.id}>
                          {flexRender(
                            cell.column.columnDef.cell,
                            cell.getContext()
                          )}
                        </td>
                      )
                    })}
                  </tr>
                )
              })}
          </tbody>
        </table>
        <div>{table.getRowModel().rows.length} Rows</div>
      
        <pre>{JSON.stringify(sorting, null, 2)}</pre>
      </div>
    )
    }
  else{
    return(
      <div>Table Loading...</div>
    )
  }
}
export default InteractiveTable;
```